# Replace the string as $test

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl

I am having many text file with different directories. I need to search one specific string and I need to replace the string with the specific value as `$test`.
I need to search the all files in all directories, for this.

Example:
In one file there is a string as `abcd`, I need to replace the string `abcd` as `$test`.
I have a script that is searching the string in all files and replacing the string. But I can't able to replace the string with `$` symbol.
Below script is working without `$`.

```
command="find \`pwd\` -name \"*\" -type f -exec grep -l \"abcd\" {} \\; 2>/dev/null | xargs  perl -pi.bak1 -w -e 's/abcd/test/g;'"
```

Below script is not working with `$` symbol.

```
command="find \`pwd\` -name \"*\" -type f -exec grep -l \"abcd\" {} \\; 2>/dev/null | xargs  perl -pi.bak1 -w -e 's/abcd/\$test/g;'"
```

How to replace the string `abcd` to `$test`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to put commands in variables (see e.g. "[How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)").

Your command is having issues with the `$` because Perl uses it on its scalar variables. You would have to escape it not only from the shell, but from Perl as well (`\\\$`).

To replace `abcd` with `$test` in all files in or below the current directory using `find` and GNU or BSD `sed`, use

```
find . -type f \
    -exec grep -qF 'abcd' {} ';' \
    -exec sed -i.bak 's/abcd/$test/g' {} ';'
```

This will find all regular files, test whether the string exists in the file, and if it does, replace it with the string `$test` (creating a backup of the original file with the suffix `.bak`).

The same thing, but using Perl:

```
find . -type f \
    -exec grep -qF 'abcd' {} ';' \
    -exec perl -pi.bak -e 's/abcd/$test/g' {} ';'
```

If you remove the `-exec grep` part, you will get backup files for all files, even though they may not have contained the string `abcd`.

Comment: I tried perl -pi.bak1 -w -e "'s/comp/\$AH/g;'" not working

Comment: @palani Same thing there, you will have to use `\\\$`. You do want to replace with the actual string `$AH`, right? Not with the value of the shell variable `$AH`?

Comment: @palani See updated answer.

Comment: you correct I need to replace the actual string as "$AH".

Comment: @Kusalanda, thank you very much, issue resolved.

Comment: @palani Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).